# Detect when the multiupload primefaces componet ends all the uploads

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I´m usig the jsf version 2.1 primefaces 5.1 and tomcat 7.

I have to execute a managed bean method after the all the uploads has been succesfully in a multiple upload component, I used the onComplete atribute, but is executed after each upload. I need to do it after the all files upload was completed. 
How identify that?

Thanks in advance for your time and answers

PD I posted this question in the primefaces [1](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=39297) forum but nobody answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
<p:fileUpload ... oncomplete="doSomething(this);" />
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" actionListener="#{bean.method}" />
```

and

```
<script>
    function doSomething(fileupload) {
        if (fileupload.files.length == 0) {
            rc();
        }
    }    
</script>
```

On the bean:

```
public void method() {
    // Do something here
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jaqen H'ghar  in the js  // Do it here
 how can i call a managed bean method?

Comment: For that you could call a remoteCommand: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml

Comment: I dont understand how to use that component for this case, because if chage the  oncomplete="doSomething(this); to oncomplete="remoteCommand"  actionListener="#{mybean.my method}" , the function   function doSomething of the js will never be called.  @Jaqen H'ghar

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks for your time and your answer @Jaqen H'ghar

Comment: The answer works except for the boolean fields. In that case if a boolean field is linked to a p:selectBooleanCheckbox or h:selectBooleanCheckbox the shown value is always "false" even if in the bean you have "true". Instead if you link a boolean field to an h:outputText the value show are "true" or "false". Is there a solution?

Comment: @Gavi Did you comment the right place? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Yes the comment is in the right place. But in order to be more clear I need to show you some snippet of code. Where can I write? In the comments paste the code is not a good idea.

Comment: Maybe you can edit my answer and paste it there. But I still don't understand, there is nothing about any other fields than a p:fileUpload in the question

Comment: Can I contact you in some way in order to show you the problem and decide if is another problem or not?

Comment: Here https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=52257 I've tried to explain the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Ah ok, sounds strange. I would say it is an unrelated problem, and you could post it on SO also (well with a minimal example for example without multiple upload etc if possible). Just to repeat everything works 100% without booleans? Are they type boolean or Boolean? I don't think I've seen the syntax where you get the object remoteButton in as a parameter and then call remoteButton() before, but it works in javascript?

Comment: Yes all is working well. The "booleanObjectField" is a Boolean. Instead the booleanField is boolean. the code of the remoteButton is in the "onComplete" attribute of the p:fileUpload. And yes it works on javascript.

Comment: I see yes. I have no explanation... I would try to make simplest possible example, or maybe try downgrade PF/JSF